# Can something be done about the text in the "Welcome New User" box?

Tags: bug, status-completed

At the moment, it reads:

> English Language and Usage is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for people who love English Language and Usage. It's 100% free, no registration required.

The first sentence seems to suggest the site is for people that love the site - maybe change it to something like:

> English Language and Usage is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for people who love the English Language and its usage. It's 100% free, no registration required.

Comment: +1, this has been bugging me too, but I couldn't be bothered reporting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deployment.